# Solving the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}_t\left\{sin\left(at^n\right)\right\}\left(s\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

I was solving an integral and i stepped in a Laplace transormation of the form $\mathcal{L}_t\left\{sin\left(at^n\right)\right\}\left(s\right)$ and I was curious on a generalized solution. After some work I wrote the following identity:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left\{sin\left(at^n\right)\right\}\left(s\right)=\frac{a}{s^{n+1}}\sum_{k\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_0}{\left(\frac{(-1)^k\left(a^2s^{-2n}\right)^k}{\left(2k+1\right)!}\Gamma\left(2kn+n+1\right)\right)}$$

where

$\sum_{k\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_0}{\left(\frac{(-1)^k\left(a^2s^{-2n}\right)^k}{\left(2k+1\right)!}\Gamma\left(2kn+n+1\right)\right)} = \frac{sin\left(a\right)}{a}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ for $n=0$ (trivial)

$\sum_{k\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_0}{\left(\frac{(-1)^k\left(a^2s^{-2n}\right)^k}{\left(2k+1\right)!}\Gamma\left(2kn+n+1\right)\right)} = \frac{s^2}{a^2+s^2}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ for $n=1$ (geometric series)

and

$\sum_{k\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_0}{\left(\frac{(-1)^k\left(a^2s^{-2n}\right)^k}{\left(2k+1\right)!}\Gamma\left(2kn+n+1\right)\right)} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}e^{-\frac{a^2}{4s}}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ for $n=\frac{1}{2}$ $\left(\Gamma\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\left(2x+1\right)!}{2^{2x+1}x!}\right)$

Do you know how to get a general closed formula of this series?

Comment: Let's clean up a bit to make the answer a little more obvious. Let $\alpha = -a^2$ and $z = s^{2n}.$ You wish to know if we can analytically continue the sum
$$\sum_{k \,\in \,\mathbb{N}} \left(\frac{\alpha}{z}\right)^k$$
Which should have a meromorphic extension away from any poles (which will of course depend on $n,$ since $z$ does) by the standard formula for a geometric series.

Comment: How did you arrive at your identity?

Comment: @DavidG Taylor expansion of the sine and geometric series

Comment: It's the [Fox-Wright function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function). Note that the sum diverges for $n > 1$.

Comment: An exact result for the integral or for the sum? The Laplace transform of $\sin(t^2)$ certainly exists, but $\sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^k \Gamma(4 k + 3)/\Gamma(2 k + 2) s^{-4 k}$ diverges.

Comment: You may want to look into the method of brackets. Here are some papers on it: https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3356, https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2062, https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08942.